# Is there a way to send links with telegram bot and show no alert on tap/click?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm developing a telegram bot and I need to send links to an external website into a channel. I noticed that when I manually paste the link in the chat, users can navigate to the website simply clicking on the link, clicking the link sent from the bot on the other hand, shows an alert to confirm the navigation

I'm using Java with custom library to interface with Telegram Bot API. I'm using SendMessage operation to send messages to the channel.

Parse mode is HTML and I'm sending a small text with an html anchor tag with the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you chose to "hide" your URL via `<a href="..."> </a>` Telegram will *always* show a confirmation window asking "Open this link?" and displaying the full link below.

You can avoid this by sending the full link instead.