# Telegram API: popup on telegram “Open this link?” How to avoid?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

This is my first post. Hope I get help here. Thanks for reading.

**Short version:**
When i send a link to my bot, Telegram show a popup "Open this link .... ?" before open the link.
I want to avoid that. Any ideas?
See also questions

- [Force closure of the popup on telegram “Open this link?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791166/force-closure-of-the-popup-on-telegram-open-this-link)
- [Is there a way to send links with telegram bot and show no alert on tap/click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943857/is-there-a-way-to-send-links-with-telegram-bot-and-show-no-alert-on-tap-click)

**Long Version:**
I have a telegram bot, which I'm sending a message from a Raspberry pi
via PHP. Background is some status notification on my smart home.
Please see code below.

I'm send a telegram message with a link attached with an inline keyboard, so that I can provide a certain responds to my smart home.
In other questions I saw that this is connected to the "parse_mode" html. I tried different modes, however the result is always the same.
Also checked the telegram api documentation for help.

- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options
- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

As this is just for myself and running only locally, I don't care about cosmetics or security.

I would appreciate any help or new ideas.

Here is my code for reference

```
function telegram($message,$maschine) {
  if (!isset($maschine)) {
    echo "no Maschine for telegram";
    exit;
  }
  if (!isset($message)) {
    echo "no Message for telegram"; exit;
  }
  $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . botToken;
    $Keyboard = [
     'inline_keyboard' =>
        [
          [
            [
              'text' => "test",
              'url' => '192.168.1.1/test.php,
            ]
          ]
        ]
    ];
    $encodedKeyboard = json_encode($Keyboard);

  $params = [
     'chat_id'=>chatId,
     'text'=> $message,
     'reply_markup' => @$encodedKeyboard,
     'one_time_keyboard' => true,
     'parse_mode'=> 'html'
  ];

  $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $jsonresult = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
  curl_close($ch);
  if ($jsonresult['ok']==false) {
    echo "Telegram Error Code: " . $jsonresult['error_code'] . " - ". $jsonresult['description'] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Telegram message send<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this is a core Telegram functionality, you cannot alter this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to send links with telegram bot and show no alert on tap/click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943857/is-there-a-way-to-send-links-with-telegram-bot-and-show-no-alert-on-tap-click)

Comment: _"As this is just for myself and running only locally, I don't care about cosmetics or security."_ - the API / service, does not know anything about "only for myself" and "only running locally." If arbitrary, non-provable conditions/circumstances like this would enable developers on a platform to disable certain security features, that would be a very bad thing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. I certinaly understand that. However what confuses me is that people replied on other questions like this "If you send the full URL, Telegram won't show this message." or "You can avoid this by sending the full link instead." But no one provided any details on how to do that.

Comment: Only thing I can determine from those other questions you referred to, is that Telegram apparently has this as a security feature, when you supply links in HTML form - so that you can't do shady things like `<a href="https://my-phishing-site">https://www.facebook.com/</a>` to try and trick users. The recommendation appears to be, to just supply the plain URL then, instead of HTML.

Comment: @CBroe. As you see in my code I'm not using <a href>... It's still not working though. So I guess it's not possible (for a maybe good reason). However still confused with the comments that you should try with "full link/URL"...

Answer (score 0):

I more or less found the answer now to my own question:
I haven't found a solution for the inline_keyboard.
If you comment the keyboard feature out and only use the link in the "text" paramater --> Then telegram is **not** asking for a extra confirmation to open the link.
See upated code below.
So issue solved. At least for me.

```
  $params = [
     'chat_id'=>chatId,
     'text'=> 'open this link: 192.168.1.1/test.php',
     //'reply_markup' => @$encodedKeyboard,
     //'one_time_keyboard' => $setting,
     'parse_mode'=> 'Markdown'
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party. But it might help someone.
The popup for me was shown because my web app was redirecting to a different url then configured for web_app url on page load.
Using the redirection url directly solved the problem for me.
For. e.g.
https://example.com => https://example.com/login